# webpack js file scope - import functions file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am learning to use `webpack` for first time. I am really stuck with something that was never a problem with `gulp`, that is the way it scopes different files.

I have a file that contains multiple standalone functions (`helpers.js`).

```
function a() {
}
function b() {
}
function c() {
}
```

Based on my [reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853611/webpack-single-scope-for-multiple-js-files) do I need to import each function separately? How do I import the whole file?

From the example in link:

a.js:

```
export var a = 4;
```

b.js

```
import { a } from "./b.js";
var b = a+1;
console.debug(b);
```

Comment: Try with `import { a } from "./b";` (not end with `.js`)

Comment: Sorry Alan, the question is how to import the external file with functions and make each function available to the global scope. Same as global variables

Comment: lol. Sorry, I haven't read your question:). You can refer this question: [ES6+ javascript module export options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494365/es6-javascript-module-export-options) I think it's good to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have used some concatenation plugin for gulp and your scope was "shared". 
With ES6 modules, you have to define exactly what functions to export and import because **the scope of each file is separate**.

So in your example, we can do it this way:

1. Create default export in helpers.js and define what data to export.

helpers.js

```
function a(){}
function b(){}
function c(){}

export default {a,b,c}
```

And import data this way:

```
import myHelpers from 'helpers'
```

Then to use helper a, you will need to call myHelpers.a()

2. Another approach is to create "named" exports

helpers.js:

```
export function a(){}
export function b(){}
export function c(){}
```

To import all data use:

```
import * as myHelpers from 'helpers'
```

Then similar to the previous example, call -> myHelpers.a()

But typing "myHelpers" is not always convenient, so here we can use named exports additional benefit - you can import it by a name, so we can do it like this:

```
import {a,b,c} from 'helpers'
```

Then you can call a()

You have to type all the names you want to import. There is no "shortcut" for that.

**Why this way?**

- better control on what exactly you import to your code, optional "tree shaking"
- no conflicts between imported modules

**Webpack - ProvidePlugin**

Ok, but what if you use those helpers really often? Do you need to import them everywhere? Technically - yes. But Webpack can automate that for us, have a look on **Webpack - ProvidePlugin** which automatically loads modules instead of having to import them everywhere.

For Webpack 3, if you go with the first solution it will look like this:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  helpers:['path/to/module/helpers', 'default'],
}),
```

That will make helpers available like a "global", and you will be able to use helpers.a()